# How to access an Embedded object?

Tags: javascript, object, ejs

I have an object embedded inside an object and don't know how to access it.

Example:

const user =
{

```
id: 60f23add03fc3f30593e8659,

message: "this is a test",
user: "{ _id: 60ee941de049e90a8d6a6bf0, username: 'test', __v: 0 }
}
```

In this case I want to access the username property. Can anyone help me?

Comment: that's not an embedded object, that's just a string, it's not JSON, so you can't parse it easily - you'll probably need a regex

Comment: Or did you improperly insert that quote before what you refer to as the object and it really is an object not a string? Considering there is no closing quote to match this appears as a typo either way. No quotes around the `_id` value is also very suspicious

Answer (score 0):

It's not a valid bit of JSON so you have to go at it with a hacksaw, and `split()`

```js
const user = {
id: "60f23add03fc3f30593e8659",
message: "this is a test",
user: "{ _id: 60ee941de049e90a8d6a6bf0, username: 'test', __v: 0 }"
}

let username = user.user.split('username:')[1].split(',')[0].replaceAll(/'/g,'').trim()
console.log(username)
```

Comment: Hacksaw and Split.... sounds like a pair of movie character names

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following is your object (cleaned up to make it valid, and updated, thanks @charlietfl )

```
const user = {
    id: '60f23add03fc3f30593e8659',
    message: 'this is a test',
    user: {
       '_id': '60ee941de049e90a8d6a6bf0', 
       username: 'test', 
       '__v': 0 
    }
}
```

Then the access would be just `user.user.username`.